# Options for processing X elements of an array at a time using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

We want to process 1000 elements of an array at a time. What are the options for doing this in Ruby?

Obviously, one approach is to do a simple loop and slice 1000 elements from the array until no more elements remain, but was curious if there are other more elegant options.

This is for a Rails app (RoR 3.2.12).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We wound up using `each_slice`:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
array.each_slice(3) do |group| 
  puts group
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In Rails you can use [in_groups_of](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-in_groups_of):

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
array.in_groups_of(3, false).each do |group| 
  puts group
end

# => [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10]]
```